# Vertical positioning of text in table cell

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

When I place an image followed by text in a table cell, the vertical alignment of the text shifts down compared to text in adjacent cells. I tried using a `line-height` CSS property, but it didn't seem to have an affect.

In the following example, I need "123 Description" to be flush with "cell one." Also, there is a space between the image and "123" by default. How can I adjust that - negative margins perhaps?

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        table { border-collapse: collapse; }
        td { border: thin solid; width: 10em;}
        /* .adjust-text { line-height: 1.3em; } */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>cell one</td>
                <td>
                   <img src="small-star.png" />
                   <span class="adjust-text">123 Description</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did any of these solutions work for you Robert?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the image is aligned with the baseline of the text, which is in effect pushing the text in that cell down.  To address this, specify:

```
td img { vertical-align: top; }
```

There's a good summary of CSS vertical-align [here](http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/).

To remove the space... remove the space:

```
<img src="http://juzzam.org:8888/AkoveServer-0.1/images/small-star.png" /><span class="adjust-text">123 Description</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s38Uv/

Comment: Note: This also works when you are using display:table-cell; on a div.

Answer (score 0):

To align your image with the cell, try putting the image in a css rule as a background image. Then adjust the y position of the background using background-position. Add a padding to the left of the element to display the text to the right of the image.

```
        table { border-collapse: collapse; }
        td { border: thin solid; width: 10em;}
        .image {
            background-image:url('http://juzzam.org:8888/AkoveServer-0.1/images/small-star.png');
            background-position: 0 -2px;
            padding-left:20px;
        }
```

```
<span class="image">123 Description</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    table { border-collapse: collapse; }
    td { border: thin solid; width: 10em;}
    td { vertical-align: baseline;}
    td img { vertical-align:  middle;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>cell one</td>
            <td>
               <img src="small-star.png" />
               <span style="margin: 0 0 0 -5;">123 Description</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried a classic `vertical-align:middle`? Else put the image in it's own cell or leave the alignment at default and change the padding-bottom of all your cells will also give you the same thing.

Comment: This won't work, look at how his example renders to see what he is talking about.

Comment: Um yeah. I don't see a link anywhere to see how it 'renders' so to speak. Where you got a full path to his image I have no idea...